# laravel backpack - creating related models on the fly

Tags: laravel-backpack

is it possible to have a onepage-form for editing or creating a entry and its related (1 to n) entrys?

For example: I have a customer model, every customer can have unlimited addresses. I could now have a CustomerCrudController and a AdressCrudController with the adress having select2-field for the customer, maybe having some kind of filter for the customer in the adress-list-view but it would be a more fluid working having the ability to change or add adresses in the customers-edit-view.

Thanks
Christin

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no built-in way to do that right now in a Backpack CRUD create/edit form. It's planned, but will not be happening until the next version of Backpack, which might take as long as 3-6 months to launch.

What you *could* do is:

1) [create your own custom field type](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-fields#section-custom-field-types), say "select_or_create_address";

2) start from the select2 field type and create your custom functionality:

- the results should could be loaded with ajax;
- a button next to the select could open a popup with the create address form, either:

  - a quick form you code yourself that inserts a new address in the db;
  - the AddressCrudController create form (but without the menu, sidebar, etc); for this you'd need to create another method in the AddressCrudController, base off CrudController::create() but loading a different view;
- when the address successfully added, the id should be inserted in the select2 as a value;

My recommendation is to go with the quick form, it should be faster to develop and you wouldn't have to resort to solutions like iFrame popups.

Cheers!

Comment: Is there a built in way to do this yet? Not necessarily a popup, but the ability to add a button to create a related model? Some of my models should only be created from another model. Thanks for the great work with Backpack.

Comment: Not yet, no; Probably in the next version, as it needs a big overhaul;